# Html root path isn't correct

Tags: html

I have a problem in my html pages

when I use "root-relative" paths it isn't make the path correctly
instead of direct to the folder of index.html it direct to the father folder.

**Example:**

My index.html is:   Websites/MySite/index.html

when I make a link in index.html to "/" it direct me to Websites/

what is the problem?

Comment: There isn't a problem. That's your root directory.

Comment: But in another pc when I open the same html files it direct me the Websites/MySite/

Answer (score 0):

Root is the first folder that your work begins. Your site root is actually Websites/. So it acts correct. Maybe some hosts consider the folder that your html file is on it as root. If you want to have no problem with this, you should make all relative links work with your main root.

There is a php function that gives your current html file path. You can use it before your links. like:

```
<?php php_function ?>/mylink
```

Answer (score 0):

The root path is a setting in the server config. If you want to reach something relative to your `index.html` than you would use `./` and `../`

You can go back with `../` and stay in the directory with `./` where the file you are using is in.

For example if you want to reach the file

```
Websites/someFile.txt
```

from your index.html in

```
Websites/MySite/index.html
```

you would have to use the relative path

```
../someFile.txt
```

and if you wanted to use the file

```
Websites/MySite/subDirectory/some.css
```

from the same index.html you would write

```
./subDirectory/some.css
```

I hope that helps, if not feel free to ask, or make you question more precise.

And if you want to read more about relative url's you can visit [the mozilla develop network ("Going back in the directory tree")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Examples_of_relative_URLs)